# Is $ \int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|)$ the same as $\int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx)$, for $b>0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Is is true that $$
\int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|) = \int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx)$$
where $b>0$?

Why would I get the same answer if I directly integrate $\int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|)$

or if I divide integration limits for $\int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx)$

It's not like I can simply rewrite $e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx)$ as $\frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|)$. Or I just can't justify it.

Answer (score 3):

If $x > 0$, then
$$\frac{x}{|x|}\sin(b|x|) = \frac{x}{x}\sin(bx) = \sin(bx).$$
If $x < 0$, then
$$\frac{x}{|x|}\sin(b|x|) = \frac{x}{-x}\sin(-bx) = (-1)^2\sin(bx) = \sin(bx).$$

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to answer whether the two integrals really are the same, remember that what you are computing is an area under the curve. It is not hard to see that there are of course many functions that will have the same area under the curve for a range from $x=-\pi/8$ to $x=\infty$, even though the functions themselves are not the same.

For example, you will have
$$
  \int_0^1 x\, dx = \frac 12 = \int_0^1 (1-x)\, dx,
$$
even though $x$ and $1-x$ are different functions.

In other words, it makes sense that there are two functions whose area under the curve is the same, even though the functions are different. Whether that is indeed the case in your example is of course a different question.

Answer (score 0):

In the interval $[-\pi/b,0)$, $|x|=-x$ and $\sin(b|x|)=-\sin(bx)$ so

$$ \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|) = e^{8x}\sin(bx) $$

and

$$ e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx) = e^{8x}\sin(bx)$$

In the interval $[0,\infty]$, $|x|=x$ and $\sin(b|x|)=\sin(bx)$ so (ignoring the removeable discontinuity at $x=0$)

$$ \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|) = e^{-8x}\sin(bx) $$

and

$$ e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx) = e^{-8x}\sin(bx)$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} \frac{x}{|x|} e^{-8|x|}\sin(b|x|) = \int_{-\pi/b}^{\infty} e^{-8|x|}\sin(bx)$$